# AR Model in Unity APK resize itself and not appearing on a device screen properly

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arkit, ar-foundation

I made up an APK from unity using AR-Foundation framework for loading my AR model on it  , and model is being loaded on a screen by scanning a QR code , which provides the details about axis and URL for model stability .

But somehow after scanning QR code , modal resizing itself .

My AR model is a size of (10-length, 10-width and 20-height) and when is being loaded on a screen , it resize itself to different size.

what should I do to resolve this.

I tried in many ways , but couldn't able to fine solution yet.